# How to unit test Ionic alertcontroller "present" function?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I wanted to unit test the alert present function that exists after creating an alert. Here is my code.

```
it('should call attempt To call alert present', async () => {
    const alert = {
      header: 'Permission Required',
      cssClass: 'alertStyle',
      message:
        'Camera permission is required to scan QR codes. You can allow this permission in Settings.',
      buttons: ['Dismiss'],
    } as HTMLIonAlertElement;
    const alertControllerStub = jasmine.createSpyObj('AlertController', ['create']);
    await component.displayBarcodeError();
    expect(alertControllerStub.create).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(alertControllerStub.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(alert);

  });
```

This basically to test this function:

```
async displayBarcodeError() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Permission Required',
      cssClass: 'alertStyle',
      message: this.translations.msg_camera,
      buttons: ['Dismiss'],
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
```

I also wanted to test this function `await alert.present();`. Can you help me understand why the code doesn't work or why it doesn't test?

I keep getting the following error:

```
Expected spy AlertController.create to have been called once. It was called 0 times.
Error: Expected spy AlertController.create to have been called once. It was called 0 times.
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/pages/home/home.page.spec.ts:278:40)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
```

I tried the above code and I want it to be a successful test.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock `alertController` earlier.

Try this (follow comments with !!):

```
// !! Declare the spy object here
let alertControllerStub: jasmine.SpyObj<AlertController>;

beforeEach(() => {
  // !! Assign it in the first beforeEach
  alertControllerStub = jasmine.createSpyObj<AlertController>('AlertController', ['create']);

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    ...
    // !! Provide the fake/stub for the real
    providers: [{ provide: AlertController, useValue: alertControllerStub }],
    ...
  });
});

it('should call attempt To call alert present', async () => {
    const alert = {
      header: 'Permission Required',
      cssClass: 'alertStyle',
      message:
        'Camera permission is required to scan QR codes. You can allow this permission in Settings.',
      buttons: ['Dismiss'],
    } as HTMLIonAlertElement;
       
    // !! Make alert controller create return something so the promise is not hang.
    // !! We have to return an object with a present method since it is called.
    alertControllerStub.create.and.resolveTo({ present: Promise.resolve(null) });

    await component.displayBarcodeError();
    expect(alertControllerStub.create).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    // !! The below test might fail because alert here and the alert when it is
    // called are different objects.
    expect(alertControllerStub.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(alert);
    // I would test them like so:
    const [alertArg, ] = alertControllerStub.create.calls.mostRecent().args;
    expect(alertArg.header).toBe('alertStyle');
  });
```